# Finding square of a number

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-operators

I found this question,

write a function that returns a square of given integer n without using multiplication.

Solution to this is

```
public static int sq(int n){
        int i = n;
        int sq = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while(i > 0){
            if((i & 1) == 1){
                sq += n << count;
            }

            i = i >> 1;
            count++;
        }

        return sq;
    }
```

I understand what the function is doing, but I don't understand why this is working.

Can anyone explain why this is a working solution?

Comment: It's just a straightforward (and inefficient) implementation of binary multiplication - which part are you having difficulty with ? Think back to how you learned to do "long hand" multiplication in elementary school.

Comment: Also note that the code is buggy - it fails for n < 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because multiplication distributes over addition. This probably sounds mysterious, but that really is the reason. Consider this multiplication:

```
100 * 111
```

Obviously that just 111 shifted left by two: 11100

This code is doing that for every bit that is 1 in `i`, and summing the results. So it turns for example `111 * 111` into

```
001 * 111 = 00111
010 * 111 = 01110
100 * 111 = 11100
            -----  +
           110001
```

Splitting the multiplication this way is allowed because multiplication distributes over addition, that is what makes `001 * 111 + 010 * 111 + 100 * 111` equal to `(001 + 010 + 100) * 111`, and now it is obviously equal to `111 * 111`.